# PyOpenSSL - verify child cert with self sign cert

Tags: ssl, certificate, self-signed, pyopenssl

I try to verify a child cert. The root cert is self signed.

In this way I create certs with cryptography and try the verify with pyOpenSSL

```
key_root = crypt.RSA.generate(2048)
key_user = crypt.RSA.generate(2048)

root_cert = crypt.Cert.generate(None,
                                key_root.private_key,
                                key_root.public_key)
user_cert = crypt.Cert.generate(root_cert,
                                key_root.private_key,
                                user_cert.public_key)

user_cert.validate_root_cert(root_cert)

## class Cert  ...
def validate_root_cert(self, root_cert):
    x509_store = crypto.X509Store()
    ## openssl_cert ---> crypto.X509.from_cryptography(...)
    x509_store.add_cert(root_cert.openssl_cert)
    x509_ctx = crypto.X509StoreContext(x509_store, self.openssl_cert)
    x509_ctx.verify_certificate()
```

Problem is now that I get the **OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreContextError: [18, 0, 'self signed certificate']** error and I don't see anyway to skip it, without a secure verify ...

Comment: A root certificate, by definition, is always self signed. Otherwise it is not a root one :-)

Comment: What is `crypt.Cert.generate`? Your `user_cert =` line is strange because you reference in it `user_cert.public_key`. So there are missing pieces in the code you show.